# Query para saber quais livros os alunos não têm, em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, sqlite

Boas, Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
Livro:
  ID_Livro PK
  Nome

Aluno:
  ID_Aluno PK
  Nome

RegistoLivroAluno:
  ID_Registo PK
  ID_Aluno   (chave extrangeira de Aluno)
  ID_Livro   (chave extrangeira de Livro)
)
```

Preciso de saber em SQL, 
Qual é a Query que consiga ver o ID_Aluno e o ID_Livro, dos que nao estao associados, ou seja que ver os livros que um determinado aluno não tem.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Qual foi o resultado? Sua pergunta é mesmo sobre MySQL, SQL Server, MySQLi e SQLite? Por favor, reveja as tags que utilizou.

Comment: A cláusula NOT EXISTS pode ser de grande ajuda. Se quiser posso dar um exemplo em PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Livros sem registro:

```
SELECT * FROM Livro WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RegistroLivroAluno WHERE RegistroLivroAluno.ID_Livro = Livro.ID_Livro);
```

Alunos sem registro:

```
SELECT * FROM Aluno WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RegistroLivroAluno WHERE RegistroLivroAluno.ID_Aluno = Aluno.ID_Aluno);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Livro
INNER JOIN RegistoLivroAluno ON RegistoLivroAluno.ID_Livro = Livro.ID_Livro
INNER JOIN Aluno ON RegistoLivroAluno.ID_Aluno = Aluno.ID_Aluno
WHERE Aluno.ID_Aluno = RegistoLivroAluno.ID_Aluno
AND Aluno.ID_Aluno =2
```

Isto é o que tenho tenho feito para mostrar os livros associados ao aluno, so que eu quero os que nao estao associados